# Jordan curve : Farthest point iteration "convergence"

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, geometric-topology, plane-curves

$J$ is a plane simple closed curve.

We build a sequence $(A_n)_n$ as follow:

$A_0$ is a point on $J$.

For $n$ natural number $n>0$ :

$A_n$ is any point in the set of points $X$ on $J$ with the distance $A_{n-1}X$ maximal.

- Can we prove ou disprove the following?

There exists a natural number $N$ and a point $A \in J$, for which:

$(A_{2n})_n=A $ , $\forall n >N$

OR

$(A_{2n+1})_n=A$ , $\forall n >N$

Comment: Do the corners of an equilateral triangle provide a counterexample to that claim?

Comment: Yes @hardmath Nice spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a sequence need not have either an even or odd indexed subsequence that is eventually constant.

For example, given an equilateral triangle as our plane closed curve, the sequence that takes each vertex in steady rotation meets the maximal distant point requirement .  However the even and odd indexed subsequences are not eventually constant.  Indeed neither of them converges, as they are essentially steady rotations through the same three vertices (but in reverse order).

Comment: Your example can be extended to every odd regular convex polygone.

Comment: It would be interesting to investigate whether an example can be constructed where the sequence has *no* constant subsequence, i.e. where the adjacent distances are strictly monotonically increasing.